# I'm having a problem with MySql in C# .Net Framework

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-4.8

I'm migrating from Access to MySql. When "btn_Ekle" is clicked, the shelf is added to the database, but the codes written afterwards do not work.

Also, RafListesi() works at first, but when we close the Add Shelves window after adding a shelf and then open it again, the shelfs are not listed. It is listed after reopening the program.

```
public static ClassRaf RafEkle(string ad)
{
    ClassRaf result;
    try
    {
        if (ClassData.RafSec(ad) != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Eklemek İstediğiniz Raf Zaten Kayıtlarda Mevcut.", "Kütüphane Sistemi | Bilgi", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            result = null;
        }
        else
        {
            MySqlCommand sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO bookrack (shelf_name) VALUES (@shelf_name)", ClassData.connectSql);
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@shelf_name", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ad;
            if (sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0)
            {
                MySqlCommand sqlCommand1 = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM bookrack ORDER BY id DESC", ClassData.connectSql);
                MySqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand1.ExecuteReader();
                if (sqlDataReader.Read())
                {
                    result = ClassData.RafSec((int)sqlDataReader["id"]);
                }
                else
                {
                    result = null;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                result = null;
            }
        }
    }
    catch
    { result = null; }
    return result;
}
```

---

```
private void btnEkle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        ClassRaf classRaf = ClassData.RafEkle(txtEkle.Text);
        if (classRaf != null)
        {
            txtEkle.Text = "";
            liste.Items.Add(classRaf.Ad);
            ClassLog.Log(string.Concat(new object[]
            {
                classRaf.Ad,
                " adlı raf eklendi.  ID=[",
                classRaf.ID,
                "]"
            }));
        ShelfValid();
        txtEkle.Select();
        }
}
```

---

```
public static List<ClassRaf> RafListesi()
{
    List<ClassRaf> result;
    try
    {
        List<ClassRaf> list = new List<ClassRaf>();
        MySqlCommand sqlCommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM bookrack", ClassData.connectSql);
        MySqlDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
        while (sqlDataReader.Read())
        {
            list.Add(new ClassRaf
            {
                ID = Convert.ToInt32(sqlDataReader["id"]),
                Ad = sqlDataReader["shelf_name"].ToString()
            });
        }
        result = list;
        sqlDataReader.Close();
        sqlDataReader.Dispose();
    }
    catch
    { result = new List<ClassRaf>(); }
    return result;
}
```

---

[public static ClassRaf RafEkle(string ad) - (Add Shelf)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lrVeL.jpg)

[private void btnEkle_Click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q68Cp.jpg)

[private void btnEkle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elyXF.jpg)

Comment: Just out of interest, if you are moving away from Access, why are you using MySql instead of MS SQL Server? Not that there's anything wrong with MySql, but given that SQL Server is a Microsoft product, you'll find a LOT more examples and help with using it from C# than you will with MySql. Also, with SQL Server, you'll find it's much easier to use Entity Framework, which is a significantly easier/more intuitive way of doing data access than writing SQL as you have shown here. You can use EF with MySql, but it's not as easy. If you're starting new, you might as well make it as easy as you can.

Comment: `catch{ result = null; }` <-- **Don't do this**: swallowing exceptions means you won't have any idea when-or-if things are going wrong...

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel Thank you for your suggestion. I will move to MS SQL. Actually, I also have in mind to migrate from C# Windows Form to ASP.NET. I may have to build from scratch for this. Do you have a suggestion for this?

Comment: If you're moving to ASP.NET (smart move by the way!), I would recommend you look at Blazor, as it's easily the best thing anyone has done for decades (in my opinion!).

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel Thank you so much. Your answers were very helpful in making my decision. I reviewed Blazor and realized that this framework is exactly what I should be using.